# Data table put into excel, rows in column read "Number Stored as Text"

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I would like to first start off by thanking anyone and everyone that is able to help me with this problem. My searches are not returning anything for this specific problem....

I have a c# application that runs a stored procedure and exports the results to an Excel file. However, one column in the report is supposed to be an Integer, but is being copied to excel as text.

The part of my query that calculates this column is as follows:

```
(str(100.0 * cast((y.NumReferrals) as INT)/cast((x.numCustomers) as INT), 6,2)) AS "Percentage"
```

I added CAST in there in hopes that it would resolve the issue but it appears as though I need to make the fix in C#. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Im not sure how to do this conversion in C# for this type of problem.

Thank you!

Comment: If the column should be an integer data type then why are you wrapping the expression in `STR()`?

Comment: Thats what Im a little confused about. My understanding is that STR() function should be used when I need to limit the number of decimal places in the results. Is there another built-in function I should use there instead?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dan Wilson, who commented above, I took a second look at the built in function I was using and came to this conclusion:

```
Cast(ROUND(100.0 * (y.NumReferrals)/(x.numCustomers),3,2) as decimal(6,2)) AS "Percentage"
```

It seems to work! Im sure there is a better way to go about this but this is the way i've been able to get it to work so I will go with this until someone else can provider better insight.

Thank you!!